# Hibernate `assigned` strategy returns 0 with sequence and trigger

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

I've Table uses Trigger and sequence to set its PK column.

The Hibernate mapping strategy for its Pk is `assigned`..

This yields in `session.save(obj)` returns object with `id=0`

How to make it returns the correct assigned PK value.

`session.getIdentifier()` doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assigned` means: Nobody generates the ID, the ID is set explicitely in the entity before persisting it.

What you want to do is impossible. Hibernate would have to insert an entity without knowing its ID, then the database would generate the ID, and Hibernate would have to reload the entity from the database to know its ID. But how would it reload the entity without knowing its ID?

The native generator does the same thing, and it works because the database provides a `getLastGeneratedId()` method which allows getting the IOD that the database has generated. But you can't do that with Oracle and a trigger.

Remove the trigger from the database, use the sequence generator, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Yes, I am very agree with you, but I cannot remember the sequence syntax for hibernate 3.2 (xml configurations)!

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id-sequences.

Comment: I would make the Trigger fires only if the PK is NULL (Oracle : `WHEN (NEW.PK_FIELD IS NULL)` )